# CakePHP emails being sent as text instead of html

Tags: email, cakephp, text

We recently switched to a new server and now when we send out our email blasts through cakePHP, users who were receiving email as html before are now getting them as code. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the format in your controller:

```
//Send as 'html', 'text' or 'both' (default is 'text')
$this->Email->sendAs = 'both'; // because we like to send pretty mail
// more code here
$this->Email->send();
```

If this was triggered by a server move, it's possible that you are missing a file rather than a line of code.  In that, case, make sure you have layouts setup for both types of email.  Here is the file structure to check:

```
app/views/layouts/email/
    html/
        default.ctp
    text/
        default.ctp
```

For more from the cookbook:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1286/Sending-a-basic-message